# IN Clause return only 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, in-clause

I have a list of links and titles in my links table and I'm trying to use an IN clause to return them but the query never returns more than a single row, and always the min row of the set.

```
SELECT title, url 
FROM opsx_links 
WHERE linkid IN('61','60','10','24','15','20','30','47')
```

This should return all 8 links as they do all exist, but it only return the info for item 10. If I remove item 10 form the list, it will then only return item 15 and so on.

Am I losing it or what?

I've Googled my butt off and can't find anyone that's had this issue.

Thanks.

-V

ok my bad here's the php code

```
public function getLinks ($data) {
   $query  = $this->db->Fetch ("SELECT title, url 
             FROM {$this->prefix}links WHERE linkid IN(" . $data . ")");
   $result = $this->db->FetchObject ($query);

   foreach ($result as $key => $value):

      $result->$key = $this->replace_strings ($value);

   endforeach;

   $this->db->Free ($query);

   return $result;
}
```

Tried this per jeron

```
$res = array();

while ($result = $this->db->FetchObject ($query)):

    $res['title'] = $result->title;
    $res['url']   = $result->url;

endwhile;
```

Now only the first row is returned instead of the minimum row.

What in the world?

Ok after much trial and error and help from all you gurus, here's the answer.

```
public function getLinks ($data) {
     $query  = $this->db->Fetch ("SELECT title, url 
               FROM {$this->prefix}links WHERE linkid IN(" . $data . ")");  
     $res = array ();
     while ($results = $this->db->FetchArray ($query)):
          $obj = new stdClass;
          $obj->title = $results['title'];
          $obj->url = $this->replace_strings($results['url']);
          $res[] = $obj;
     endwhile;

     $this->db->Free ($query);

     return (object)$res;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: what's the data type of linkid?

Comment: Show your PHP code. My bet is on a single call to `mysql_fetch_*()` when you should be calling it in a loop.

Comment: Have you tried selecting count(*) with that predicate?

Comment: show us some records, is `linkid` varchar? because if it is numeric, is should be `IN (61,60,10,...)`

Comment: @NiftyDude data type is TINYINT(3)

Comment: @dldnh no I haven't but I'll try that now and report back.

Comment: @johntotetwoo I've tried it both ways with single quotes and without and I get the same result.

Comment: @Michael I'm trying to fetch the results in an object, but I've tried both and I get the same result.

Comment: @VinceKronlein object or array doesn't matter - is it being called in a `while` loop? If not, it needs to be -- that's why I asked to see the code (and 8 others agreed with me)

Comment: What is `$data` in the code above? Is it a string or array? If it's an array,it needs to be converted to a string.  And does `FetchObject` return a multi-dimensional array of objects or a single object?

Comment: Did you try your query in phpMyAdmin ? if you don't have all data that is a sql problem, if you do it's a PHP problem

Comment: $data is shown in the original question above:

'61','60','10','24','15','20','30','47'

It's a string. I already converted it in the controller before passing it to the model.

FetchObject returns mysql_fetch_object

Comment: BTW counting the query does return 8.  So I assume I'm missing a loop somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** You are only getting one result from the results set:

```
$result = $this->db->FetchObject ($query);
```

Should be something like:

```
$my_results = array();
while ($result = $this->db->FetchObject ($query))
{
  // make a new / clone the object, add it to the array and do the processing
}
return $my_results;
```

Comment: @jeron it's supposed to be overwritten, it does a string replace on ##VARIABLE## with a constant for each link.  Plus it's an object not an array.

Comment: @Vince Kronlein Sorry, I did not read it carefully enough, you need to call `$result = $this->db->FetchObject ($query);` in a loop, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Still no love.

I tried the code added to the question and it's still returning only one row, but now just the first row.

Comment: @Vince Kronlein In your last line you are casting your array of objects to a single object. It should work if you don't do that.